# firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber + express on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've got a trouble when trying to implement backend firebase Authorization.
After I had read carefully the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth), I figured out that Authorization need to be proceded by two steps:

1. send phone
2. send code

I divided Google's example on two promises, but can't understand how to store current user and  whether or not I've done everything in an appropriate way.

```
  app.post("/appSignInByPhone", (req, res) => {
        let {phoneNumber, applicationVerifier} = req.body;
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, applicationVerifier)
            .then(() => res.end("Waiting for code"))
            .catch(
                error => res.json(error)
            );
});

app.post("/appSignInPhoneVerify", (req, res) => {
        let {verificationCode} = req.body;
            firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode)
            .then( user => res.json(user))
            .catch(
                error => res.json(error)
            );
});
```

Maybe there are some ways of merging these to request to one...

Comment: You're attempting to run authentication from your backend server. This will not work since `applicationVerifier` depends on a reCAPTCHA which has to be rendered on a web page client side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. But if frontend will send me this reCaptcha in a request?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. If you insist on doing this on the backend even though I don't recommend it. You would run `signInWithPhoneNumber` on the client and then when it resolves, send the  `confirmationResult.verificationId` and the SMS code provided by the user to your backend, initialize a `firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code)` with these 2 and then `signInWithCredential` to complete sign in on your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

In step #1 either store or send back the `confirmationResult` you get from the fulfillment handler:

```
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, applicationVerifier)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
               // either store confirmationResult 
               // or send it to the client and ask for it in step #2)
         }).catch(
            error => res.json(error)
        );
```

then in step #2:

```
     // get the confirmationResult from the client or from some storage
     // in the server
     // for example let { verificationCode, confirmationResult } = req.body;
        confirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode)
        .then( user => res.json(user))
        .catch(
            error => res.json(error)
        );
```

Comment: I am getting error passing: applicationVerifier, while converting it to Json string and sent it using xhr request.